# "It is a time" vs. "it is time"

Tags: articles

Is it correct to say "*It is **a** time to get up!*" when I mean a very specific time or is the only correct way to say it "*It is time to get up!*"?

Comment: You could say *It's a time to get up* to refer to a specific time (eg 0700) but it's just not idiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*It is a time* does not make sense as the indefinite article is used to talk about a **non-specific** object.

Instead, you could use the definite article (*the*) which is used to talk about a specific object:

> it is the time

This could them fit into your sentence but it is not the idiomatic phrase.

> It is the time to get up!

This wording would be used to talk about a specific time frame, such as:

> Dawn is the time to get up!
>   Christmas is the time to celebrate.

When talking abut waking up, more natural is the phrase practised by parents everywhere:

> It is time to get up!

Or, if they're child's particularly lazy, they could use the imperative mood:

> Get up!

Comment: The indefinite article can be used to talk about ***either*** a specific or non-specific referent. In either case  it's an indefinite reference. Which is why it's called the *indefinite article* not something like the *unspecific article*. Specificity and definiteness are two different qualities.

Comment: "A time" is used to comment on some aspect of the time under discussion. For instance if a teenager did not stir until early afternoon one of his parents might say "What a time to get up!" Also if someone was talking to a friend about leaving home at 2:30 to catch a flight at 5:00am the friend might say "What a time to set off!"

Comment: @BoldBen Yes, *What a time to set off!* makes sense because it is not being definite about the time (this is **a** notable time to set off, not **the**).